# How to migrate oracle users to WSO2 identity server

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I want to authenticate users with WSO2 EI 6.1.1. I already have the users, passwords and granted roles defined in Oracle database. Now I deployed the identity server scripts but couldn't find a way to migrate my users and roles to WSO2.

Is there standard methods available for this kind of thing or should I have to directly insert into the tables?
In that case, which tables should I touch?

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2IS exposes many helpful SOAP services. One of them is to add a user to existing user store.

The easiest  way I can think of to solve your problem is to write a script (may be a JAVA code) to get info from your Oracle database, and then call WSO2 webservice to add user in WSO2 database.

Let me know if you need any help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your database schema isn't the same as that of WSO2 User Database schema, you need to write a custom user store manager to use your existing users, passwords.

Here is a complete guide on how to do this:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager